# CSS3 border-image and Retina screens

Tags: css, border, retina-display, border-image

My question is pretty simple, is there a way (or a hack) to make 'border-image' property support Retina (high definition) displays? At least in Webkit-based browsers. If I try to use a high resolution image in border-image, it just appears larger, and I found no way of scaling it down. If I set a smaller border width and/or slice size, it would (naturally) crop the image, not scale it down. I know I could simulate a border with backgrounds, but in this question I am more interested to know if there's a way to use 'border-image'. Thank you in advance!

This is my example:

```
<style>
.border-button {
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(button-border.png) 20 20 repeat;
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .border-button {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(button-border@2x.png) 10 10 repeat;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very silly of me, but I haven't tried setting 'border-width' to half the size of the border image slice. It scales the image down fine, and this is the correct answer. I apologise for posting a question that is so obvious, but perhaps it will help others who don't see this obvious in front of them, like me :)